# Dynamic Community Home Page based on user profile

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community

So I have requirement that I have problem with.

So as in title:

Depending on the profile which community user have, home page of the community should change. So for example it should have list of tasks and not cases, or on one chatter feed should be presented and on another not.

I was thinking about building custom theme layout component like [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder_theme_layout.htm)

but I dont have a clue if it is correct approach.
Any advices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a simple way to do this using the Profile and the Audiences feature in the Community Builder.

If you go to the Community Builder and then select the Home page and select the widget for Page Properties.

[image]

A popup will open with an option for Page Variations then create a new page variation and these can then be assigned to different profiles using the audiences feature. The following images show how to do this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sadly this doesn't always help, e.g. if you have a Hero component then it's settings persist across variations :(